# How do I fill my nav bar completely such that there are no unused empty spaces?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

As you can see in the picture attached, what I'm trying to do is to spread out tab 1 to tab 7 such that it fills up the shaded area in orange (on the right)

[image: a screen shot of what i currently have]

in my layout.html, i have:

```html
<nav class="nav nav-fill navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top
  container-fluid">
  <a class="navbar-brand mr-4 ml-4" href="#"><b>Home</b></a>
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
      <a class="relative nav-item nav-link mx-auto" href="#">Tab 1</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1" href="#>Tab 2</a>
      {% if user.is_authenticated %}
      <a class="nav-item nav-link col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1" href="#"
      >Tab 3</a
      >
      {% block searchform %}{% endblock searchform %}
      <a class="nav-item nav-link col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1" href="#"
      >Tab 4</a
      >
      <a class="nav-item nav-link col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1" href="#">Tab 5</a>
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      Tab 6</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Inbox{% if unread_count %} <strong>({{ unread_count }})</strong>{% endif %}</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Write</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sent</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Archives</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Trash</a>
      </div>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1" href="#"
      >Tab 7</a
      >
      <a
      class="nav-item nav-link btn btn-danger btn-sm text-light col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1"
      href="{% url 'logout' %}"
      >Logout</a
      >
      {% else %}
      <a
      class="nav-item nav-link btn btn-success btn-sm col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1 text-light"
      href="#"
      >Login</a
      >
      <a
      class="nav-item nav-link btn btn-info btn-sm col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1 text-light"
      href="{% url 'register' %} "
      >Register</a
      >
      {% endif %}
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

How can I overcome this? Can any one guide me? Thank you very much!!

Comment: Using `flexbox`

Comment: hey, thanks for replying this quickly. May i know where would it go and how would i go about doing it? I've read something about d-flex, d-inline-flex and tried adding them into the HTML above but it's not really working. Do you know where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at this once, is it this you want to Acheive ?? or anything else ??

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Portfolid</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
    .hello{
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: row;
     }

     .world{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <nav class="nav d-flex flex-row justify-content-between nav-fill navbar-expand- 
     lg navbar-dark bg-dark sticky-top
      container-fluid" style="">
      <div class="hello">
     <a class="navbar-brand mr-4 ml-4 flex-1" href="#"><b>Home</b></a>
     <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
      <div class="navbar-nav d-flex flex-row">
        <a class="relative nav-item nav-link mx-auto" href="#">Tab 1</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1" href="#>Tab 2</a>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <a class="nav-item nav-link col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1" href="#"
        >Tab 3</a
        >
        <!-- {% block searchform %}{% endblock searchform %} -->
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

    <div class="world">
          <a class="nav-item nav-link col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1" href="#"
          >Tab 4</a
          >
          <a class="nav-item nav-link col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1" href="#">Tab 5</a>
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Tab 6</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Inbox{% if unread_count %} <strong>({{ unread_count }})</strong>{% endif %}</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url '#' %}">Write</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url '#' %}">Sent</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url '#' %}">Archives</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url '#%}">Trash</a>
          </div>
          <a class="nav-item nav-link col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1" href="{% url 'friend_list' %}"
          >Tab 7</a
          >
          <a
          class="nav-item nav-link btn btn-danger btn-sm text-light col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1"
      href="{% url 'logout' %}"
      >Logout</a
      >
      <!-- {% else %} -->
      <a
      class="nav-item nav-link btn btn-success btn-sm col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1 text-light"
      href="#"
      >Login</a
      >
      <a
      class="nav-item nav-link btn btn-info btn-sm col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1 text-light"
      href="{% url 'register' %} "
      >Register</a
      >
      <!-- {% endif %} -->
    </div>
</nav>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey, although its not what i'm looking for but i wanna thank you for taking the time out to type all these, I really appreciate it! Is it possible to spread all 9 tabs (tab1 to tab7, search bar and logout) out equally such that it fills up the entire navigation bar and also resizes automatically to different resolution?

Comment: heres's how it looks like now: https://imgur.com/OwcSxGv

Comment: oh no. I want it to be like what I've described but the picture is what you have given me

Comment: that's the  thing I did in my solution

Answer (score 1):

Check the instructions to use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

What you need to do is

1. Give `display: flex;` to parent.
2. Give `flex: 1` to childs.